# Вызов разных функций по клику на разных "детей" элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется html, который генерируется автоматически и дается мне такой какой есть:

```
<li class="test1" title="title1-gen">
   <span class="inner-class"data="0">×</span>Select1
</li>
```

Я пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы по клику на **Select1** у меня выполнялась одна функция, а по клику на **×** выполнялась, соответственно, другая.

Я пробовал самым простым вариантом:

```
$('.test1[title="title1-gen"]').on('click', function() {
     $('.inner-class').on('click', function() {
          alert('NO');
          return;
     });
     alert('YES');
});
```

Но при нажатии на крест все равно показывается **YES**. Пробовал выносить `$('.inner-class')` отдельно, менять `data` и проверять его, но все равно вызывается **YES**. Можно ли вообще провернуть подобное?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы по **каждому** клику на `<li>` добавляете дополнительный обработчик события click для внутреннего элемента, что в корне неверно

Можно сделать два обработчика событий:

```js
$('.test1[title="title1-gen"]').on('click', function() {
  alert('YES');
});

$('.test1[title="title1-gen"] .inner-class').on('click', function() {
  alert('NO');
  return false;
});
```

```html
<li class="test1" title="title1-gen">
   <span class="inner-class"data="0">×</span>Select1
</li>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Ключевым моментом тут является то, что при клике по `.inner-class` нужно блокировать всплытие события (например, с помощью `return false`), чтобы не вызвался обработчик родительского элемента

---

В принципе, можно обойтись и одним обработчиком события, выясняя по `event.target` на что конкретно нажали, но особых преимуществ я в таком подходе не вижу:

```js
$('.test1[title="title1-gen"]').on('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains("inner-class")) {
    alert('NO');
  }
  else {
    alert('YES');
  }
});
```

```html
<li class="test1" title="title1-gen">
   <span class="inner-class"data="0">×</span>Select1
</li>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Круто! Спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

Обычно в таких вопросах решение кроется в запрещении "всплытия" события клика. В вашей разметке вы пытаетесь навесить обработчики на элементы, один  из которых является потомком второго.
В итоге когда вы кликаете на дочерний элемент, сначала отрабатывается его клик, а далее событие "всплывает" вверх по дереву DOM. Чтобы верхний обработчик не вызывался, необходимо предотвратить всплытие, используя `stopPropagation()`.

*Вдобавок в вашем коде, обработчик нажатия на крестик навешивается внутри обработчика селекта, что приводит к тому, что простой клик на крестик не работает, пока не кликнут сам селект.*

```js
$(".test1").click(function(){
   console.log('select');
});

$(".inner-class").click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   console.log('x');
});
```

```css
.inner-class { margin-right: 10px; font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="test1" title="title1-gen">
   <span class="inner-class"data="0">×</span>Select1
</li>
```

Comment: То что клик на крестик начинает работать только после клика по селекту - это ещё полбеды. Вот когда обработчиков клика по крестику становится с десяток и больше - начинается "самое веселье"